# Is $Pr(x \leq C)$ equal to $Pr(\sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{C})$?

Tags: probability, distributions

Where x is non-negative continuous random variable and C is a constant.

Comment: I think you need C to be a non-negative constant also.  Otherwise its square root is imaginary and the inequality makes n sense.

Comment: I don't see why x needs to be continuous.

Comment: Yes, it does not have to be continuous, and C should be non-negative constant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, because $x \leq C \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{C}$ for $x, C \geq 0$.

This means that the set of events $\{A \in \Omega: x(A) \leq C\}$ equals the set $\{A \in \Omega: \sqrt{x(A)} \leq \sqrt{C}\}$, so are their probabilities.